# How to connect with computer

Tags: mixer

I have Yamaha MG10XU MIXER wondering how to connect it with computer? I have cable for it and tried to connect it but didn't see any output.  Is there any software require for it? It didn't come with any software

Thx

Comment: The default USB protocol for this mixer is Mac / iPad and a few other Apple products.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your PC's operating system, you might need to install a driver for the Yamaha USB interface to be recognized by your PC. Yamaha support site provides such drivers for downloading. As there are only windows driver, I would think that an Apple computer doesn't require driver download.

Once the driver is installed, you should see one additional stereo input and one additional stereo output in your PC operating system sound/audio panel.

If you want to record the output of the mixer on your PC, you need an audio recording application, in which you will have to select the Yamaha interface as input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a software. There are numerous free DAW. All you need to do is connect the device and your computer should detect it properly. If not, then you have to find the drivers.
Depending on the DAW, you should map the controls in your mixer